# blur not working for data table pagination

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a table with textarea as one of the field.I have added datatable for the table having 5 items per page.I want to append textarea value to data-comment attribute on blur event. blur append value only in first page but not in second page.
I want to append value also in second page of datatable pagination.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var table_home = $('#home_approval').DataTable({                    
             dom: 'ltp',
             "oLanguage": {
                  "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "<",
                    "sNext": ">"
                    }
                  }, 
      "lengthMenu": [5,10, 25],
                  "ordering": false,
      "searching": false,
      "iDisplayLength": 5
 });
  $('.comment_update').blur(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-comment', $(this).val());
    }); 

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered tablesorter reportTable dataTable no-footer" id="home_approval" role="grid">
  <thead class="thead-inverse"> 
  <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;"><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)"> <br></th><th title="Request Id" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 84px;">Request Id</th><th title="Requestor Name" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;">Name</th><th title="Requestor ACE number" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 84px;">ACE number</th><th title="Department" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;">Practice / Unit</th><th title="Customer" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;">Customer</th><th title="Project" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;">Project</th><th title="Comment" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;">Comment</th><th title="Asset Type" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 58px;">Type</th><th title="Category" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 101px;">Category</th><th class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" title="Sub-category" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 101px;">Sub-category</th><th title="Quantity" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 24px;">Qty</th><th title="Status" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 102px;">Status</th></tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody>
         <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="4">                               
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="143" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0143" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0143</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="janaki.jayachandran">janaki.jayachandran</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0021">ACE0021</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Testing(SL)">Testing(SL)</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Testing">Testing</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="B1">B1</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="WO Network">WO Network</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
           Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0143" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="10">                               
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="113" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0113" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0113</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="sridhar.ps">sridhar.ps</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE1753">ACE1753</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Management">Management</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems Inc">Aspire Systems Inc</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="DialdeIN">DialdeIN</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Laptop">
           Laptop
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0113" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="130" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0130" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0130</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="ramesh.babu">ramesh.babu</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE2025">ACE2025</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Testproject asset5">Testproject asset5</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Software">Software</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
            Software
         </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="w">w</td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0130" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="2">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="145" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0145" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0145</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="binu.john">binu.john</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0192">ACE0192</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems Inc">Aspire Systems Inc</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="DialdeIN">DialdeIN</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="asdas" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
           Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0145" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="142" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0142" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0142</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="ashay.chourey">ashay.chourey</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE3455">ACE3455</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Retail(SL)">Retail(SL)</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Retail Testing">Retail Testing</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="World of Jeans &amp; Tops, Inc dba Tillys">World of Jeans &amp; Tops, Inc dba Tillys</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="TLS QA">TLS QA</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
           Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="123">123</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0142" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr>
  
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="134" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0134" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0134</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="ajith.ravi">ajith.ravi</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE3880">ACE3880</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Testing(SL)">Testing(SL)</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Aria">Aria</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="test customer">test customer</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Nothing_1">Nothing_1</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Laptop">
           Laptop
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="3">3</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0134" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="2">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="72" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0072" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0072</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="finny.chellakumar">finny.chellakumar</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0839">ACE0839</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Management">Management</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Business Analysis">Business Analysis</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Business Analyst">Business Analyst</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Software">Software</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
            Software
         </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="234">234</td>
  <td title="324">324</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0072" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="56" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0056" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0056</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="lakshmanan.shankar">lakshmanan.shankar</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE2842">ACE2842</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Development">Development</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title=".Net">.Net</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Finbetween bvba">Finbetween bvba</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="FB - CreditManager">FB - CreditManager</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Software">Software</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
            Software
         </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="ert">ert</td>
  <td title="3">3</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0056" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">      <!-- Request status for finance admin-->
           
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0122" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0122</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="murali.venkatesan">murali.venkatesan</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE2629">ACE2629</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Development">Development</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Java">Java</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Coalesce, Inc">Coalesce, Inc</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Spectra">Spectra</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width" title="approved in popup">approved in popup</td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
           Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="1">1</td>
  <td title="Waiting for approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for approval</td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="2">      <!-- Request status for finance admin-->
           
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0120" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0120</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="binu.john">binu.john</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0192">ACE0192</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Testproject asset8">Testproject asset8</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width" title="approved">approved</td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Others">
           Others
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="dg">dg</td>
  <td title="4">4</td>
  <td title="Waiting for approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for approval</td>  </tr></tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use draw, this will callback once page has changed and new page is loaded
You can read the documentation here: https://datatables.net/manual/events.

This will actually work with all the events, paging, sorting, searching.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table_home = $('#home_approval').DataTable({
        dom: 'ltp',
        "oLanguage": {
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "<",
                "sNext": ">"
            }
        },
        "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25],
        "ordering": false,
        "searching": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 5
    });

    //binding draw dt so it will callback once page
    table_home.on('draw.dt', function() {

        bindCommentUpdateEvent();
    });
    //binding the comment update event
    function bindCommentUpdateEvent() {

        $('.comment_update').unbind('blur');
        $('.comment_update').blur(function() {
            $(this).attr('data-comment', $(this).val());
        });
    }
    bindCommentUpdateEvent();


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered tablesorter reportTable dataTable no-footer" id="home_approval" role="grid">
  <thead class="thead-inverse"> 
  <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;"><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)"> <br></th><th title="Request Id" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 84px;">Request Id</th><th title="Requestor Name" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;">Name</th><th title="Requestor ACE number" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 84px;">ACE number</th><th title="Department" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;">Practice / Unit</th><th title="Customer" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;">Customer</th><th title="Project" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;">Project</th><th title="Comment" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 100px;">Comment</th><th title="Asset Type" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 58px;">Type</th><th title="Category" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 101px;">Category</th><th class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" title="Sub-category" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 101px;">Sub-category</th><th title="Quantity" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 24px;">Qty</th><th title="Status" class="fixed_width sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 102px;">Status</th></tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody>
         <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="4">                               
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="143" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0143" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0143</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="janaki.jayachandran">janaki.jayachandran</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0021">ACE0021</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Testing(SL)">Testing(SL)</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Testing">Testing</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="B1">B1</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="WO Network">WO Network</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
           Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0143" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="10">                               
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="113" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0113" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0113</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="sridhar.ps">sridhar.ps</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE1753">ACE1753</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Management">Management</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems Inc">Aspire Systems Inc</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="DialdeIN">DialdeIN</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Laptop">
           Laptop
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0113" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="130" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0130" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0130</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="ramesh.babu">ramesh.babu</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE2025">ACE2025</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Testproject asset5">Testproject asset5</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Software">Software</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
            Software
         </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="w">w</td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0130" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="2">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="145" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0145" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0145</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="binu.john">binu.john</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0192">ACE0192</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems Inc">Aspire Systems Inc</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="DialdeIN">DialdeIN</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="asdas" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
           Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="2">2</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0145" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="142" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0142" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0142</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="ashay.chourey">ashay.chourey</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE3455">ACE3455</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Retail(SL)">Retail(SL)</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Retail Testing">Retail Testing</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="World of Jeans &amp; Tops, Inc dba Tillys">World of Jeans &amp; Tops, Inc dba Tillys</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="TLS QA">TLS QA</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
           Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="123">123</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0142" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr>
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
         
  
  
          
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="134" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0134" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0134</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="ajith.ravi">ajith.ravi</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE3880">ACE3880</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Testing(SL)">Testing(SL)</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Aria">Aria</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="test customer">test customer</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Nothing_1">Nothing_1</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Laptop">
           Laptop
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="3">3</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0134" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="2">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="72" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0072" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0072</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="finny.chellakumar">finny.chellakumar</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0839">ACE0839</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Management">Management</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Business Analysis">Business Analysis</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Business Analyst">Business Analyst</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Software">Software</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
            Software
         </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="234">234</td>
  <td title="324">324</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0072" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">                
        <td><input id="select_update" data-id="56" name="select_update" type="checkbox"></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0056" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0056</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="lakshmanan.shankar">lakshmanan.shankar</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE2842">ACE2842</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Development">Development</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title=".Net">.Net</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Finbetween bvba">Finbetween bvba</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="FB - CreditManager">FB - CreditManager</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width"><textarea id="comment" data-comment="" class="comment_update" maxlength="150" name="comment" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea></td>  <td title="Software">Software</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Software">
            Software
         </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="ert">ert</td>
  <td title="3">3</td>
  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink fixed_width" title="Waiting for NSA Approval" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0056" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>Waiting for NSA Approval</a></td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="1">      <!-- Request status for finance admin-->
           
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0122" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0122</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="murali.venkatesan">murali.venkatesan</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE2629">ACE2629</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Development">Development</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Java">Java</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Coalesce, Inc">Coalesce, Inc</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Spectra">Spectra</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width" title="approved in popup">approved in popup</td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Mobile/Tablet">
           Mobile/Tablet
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title=""></td>
  <td title="1">1</td>
  <td title="Waiting for approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for approval</td>  </tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
    <input class="role_id" name="requestor_role" type="hidden" value="2">      <!-- Request status for finance admin-->
           
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>  <td class="request-edit viewPopLink" id="app-rej" data-id="1819AM0120" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal"><a>1819AM0120</a></td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="binu.john">binu.john</td>
  <td class="" title="ACE0192">ACE0192</td>
  <!-- <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td> -->
      <td class="fixed_width" title="Information Systems">Information Systems</td>  
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited">Aspire Systems (India) Private Limited</td>
   <td class="fixed_width" title="Testproject asset8">Testproject asset8</td> 
  <td class="fixed_width" title="approved">approved</td>  <td title="Hardware">Hardware</td>
    <td class="fixed_width" title="Others">
           Others
      </td>
  <td class="fixed_width" title="dg">dg</td>
  <td title="4">4</td>
  <td title="Waiting for approval" class="fixed_width">Waiting for approval</td>  </tr></tbody>
  </table>
```